# Anchor tag connected to link based on class, not id

Tags: html, css

I'm putting in some skip navigation on a client's site that is using a CMS that puts in the navigational links. The CMS does not allow for putting in ids but it does for class.

Normally I would do something like:

```
<a href="/about#about-us-content">Skip to About Us Content</a>

<div id="about-us-content">Insert stuff</div>
```

Is there a way to connect from the anchor tag to the div using class instead?

Comment: No because if there were more than one element with the class, you wouldn't be able to point to the one you want. The reason this works with IDs is because you can always rely on the fact that you will jump to the only element with said ID in a conforming document.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with just HTML. There are a lot of ways to accomplish this with JS.

Comment: I was actually planning on using singular use of class. The alternative I have that comes to mind is rewriting the navigation outside of the CMS

Comment: `document.querySelector(".class").scrollIntoView()`